# Visual Basic VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I would like to auto run below statements:

=VLOOKUP(B8,Sheet2!D:H,5,FALSE)

But I got an error at line 6: unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("B8:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

        For i = 18 to rng.Rows.Count
             rng.Cells(8, 6) = 
 Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(i,1), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D:H"), 5, False)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Where I want to put my output at SheetT F8, by looking up Sheet2

Comment: *I got an error* is an absolutely useless problem description unless you tell us what that *error* was. It's right in front of you on your screen. There is no excuse for failing to include it in your question so we have that information as well. You're asking for *free help* to solve *your problem* - it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible to help you by giving us the details that you have *right on the screen in front of you*.

Comment: Line 6 is `Set rng = .Range("B8:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)`.  The only thing I can see that could cause an error on that line would be if `ActiveSheet` was a `Chart`.  Are you sure it was line 6 and not line 9 (which is missing a line continuation character, i.e. `_`, at the end of it)?

Comment: P.S. Do you realise that `rng.Cells(8, 2)` is the equivalent of worksheet cell `C15` (assuming column A has information in cell A8 or below)?  Are you sure you want to set `C15` to the result of doing a `VLookup` using the 8th last cell in column A as the value to match?

Comment: OK, if you have managed to get past the missing continuation character and got to the `VLookup` in line 10, are you sure that the value in A5 (A6, A7, etc) exists in column  D of `Sheets("Yield_comparison")`?

Comment: OK, if you now start the loop at row 18, have you made sure that the value in A18 (A19, A20, etc) exists in column D of `Sheets("Yield_comparison")`?

Comment: updated Error Message

Comment: And I now notice that one of the edits changed your code to write to cell G15 instead of C15.  (`rng.Cells(8, 6)` is the equivalent of worksheet cell `G15`.)

Comment: Actually i put Cells (8,6) is I want my output to be displayed at E8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **suspect** you want

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 8 to .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(i, "F").Value = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, "B").Value, _
                                                       Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D:H"), _
                                                       5, _
                                                       False)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Your original code was:

- always writing to `rng.Cells(8, 6)`, which is a cell that was `B8` offset by 7 rows and 5 columns, i.e. `G15` (or `C15` in an earlier version)
- using `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)` as the lookup value, which was a cell in column A

Comment: subscript out of range

Comment: @iop Do you have a sheet called "Sheet2"?  (I based my code on your current question, not the question when it was calling the other sheet `Sheets("Yield_comparison")`.)

Comment: yup, i rename back then it work well, thank you so much :)